# Adding 3 UIViewControllers in Single UIView-programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

**This is what i am doing**

**1.** *I am adding a UIView of width 960 on  FirstViewController through xib so that it can accomodate 3 view controller*

**2.** *Then I am trying to add  3 viewcontrollers as subview  on that view , by programmatically setting the frame*

**Problem:**
While changing the x coordinate to 320 it is not showing the second view..

This is the code :-
Currently i am trying with 2 views

```
#pragma mark - SetupView View

-(void)setupView

{
    //setting up Interval Home Screen on Container View
    intervalHome=[[IntervalHomeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"IntervalHomeViewController" bundle:nil];

    CGRect f=self.containerView.frame;
    f.size.width=self.view.frame.size.width;
    intervalHome.view.frame=f;
    [self.containerView addSubview:intervalHome.view];

    [intervalHome.btnAddCustomInterval addTarget:self action:@selector(addCustomIntervalScreen:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [intervalHome.btnAddInterval addTarget:self action:@selector(addIntervalScreen:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //setting up AddInterval screen on Container View

    addInterval=[[AddIntervalViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AddIntervalViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.containerView addSubview:addInterval.view];
    CGRect frame=f;
    frame.origin.x+=self.view.frame.size.width;
    addInterval.view.frame=frame;
    addInterval.view.tag=99;



      NSLog(@"Frameinterval=%@",self.addInterval.view);
}


#pragma mark - Switch to addInterval view

-(IBAction)addIntervalScreen:(id)sender
{

    NSLog(@"Frame=%@",self.containerView);
    CGRect frame=self.containerView.frame;
    frame.origin.x+=self.view.frame.size.width;
    self.containerView.frame = CGRectMake( frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width,frame.size.height );
    NSLog(@"Frame2=%@",self.containerView);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use UIPageViewController which is made exactly for that scenario :-)